# SEO Friendly URL for search keywords

Tags: seo, url

I have a website where you can search for a brands, item, and content inside my web. It was designed with tab for each search type, but I want to make the url when changing the tab user friendly and good for SEO.

Is it better to have a url for search result like this

```
www.example.com/search/{search_keyword}/{tab}
```

or

```
www.example.com/search/{search_keyword}?tab={tab}
```

or

```
www.example.com/search/?search={search_keyword}&tab={tab}
```

where {search_keyword} is the keyword that user input, and {tab} is either brands / item / content, because when I look at facebook, stackoverflow, and some other website, they use query string for their search keyword

### Edit

My past url is only `www.example.com/search/{search_keyword}`, and I just added the tab design recently. Consider that I should go with option 1 from the above option, should I make `www.example.com/search/{search_keyword}` the default for 1 of the 3 tab, and make the other 2 tab with `www.example.com/search/{search_keyword}/{tab}` to retain the score for the page, or should I make all the tab url with

```
www.example.com/search/{search_keyword}/{tab}
```

and use a permanent redirect from `www.example.com/search/{search_keyword}` to one of the url tab

Comment: Generally URLs should be for users and not search engines, search engines aren't likely to crawl by searching unless they are hyperlinks somewhere on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is best since query string parameters are generally ignored by search engines.

Anything that can be used to "game" a search engine isn't going to count for much. You could have endless spammy keywords as parameters in a URL without effecting the page content so why would a search engine take any notice of them?

But, much more importantly, it's best because it's easier for real *people* to use and understand. That's the most important thing. Forget trying to appease search engines and think about your users. They'll appreciate it and, if your content is good, maybe they'll give you a backlink - search engines really like backlinks.

Comment: consider if I'm using the 1st option. My past url is only www.example.com/search/{search_keyword}, and I just added the tab design recently. Should I make the /search/{key} the default for 1 of the tab, and make the url with /{tab} for the other, or should I make all the tab with the /{tab} url. If I should go with the 2nd option, should I make a permanent redirection from the url without /{tab} to url with /{tab}

Comment: query string parameters are generally ignored by search engines ?

Comment: Yes. They will read *some* of the parameters (say the first 3) and will use them to determine indexing but given they make it trivial to spam keywords into a URL and that a "clean" url is nice for users there is little point to use them if you can avoid it.

Comment: Kyojimaru I'm sorry I don't really understand what you are asking. You should use whatever makes sense for your users in the context of your site.